# Reset PHP cache via command line

Tags: php, cmd

When I try to reset cache from command line with:

```
php -r "opcache_reset();"
```

I get the following error message:

> Call to undefined function opcache_reset() in Command line code on
>   line 1

Is there a way to add the opcache_reset function to PHP via php.ini or something like this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your php.ini config files.

Option 1)
Enable the following flag in your opcache config, likely under mods-available

```
opcache.enable_cli
```

Option 2)
If you have different config for CLI and apache2/fpm then check the CLI version has enabled opcache